# Filling Option List With Data Returned From JSON Request

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON response form the server the response is an List Object with three columns. However to fill the select option list i only need to use two. I am able to receive the data on the client however i am unable to fill the select option list.

**Jquery**

```
$("select#offenceCatId").change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'getCrimeTypeList.htm',
        data:{crimeCatId: $(this).val()},

        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            var crimeType = JSON.stringify(data);
            var options = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < crimeType.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + crimeType.crimeTypeId[i] + '">' + crimeType.crimeTypeDesc[i] + '</option>';
            }
            $("select#offenceTypeId").html(options);
        }
    });
});
```

**JSON Data**

[{"crimeTypeDesc":"Incitement To Murder","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":39},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Sexual and Non Sexual Assults","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":40},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Pornography","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":41},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Censorship","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":42},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Statutory Rape","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":43},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Criminal Transmission Of HIV","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":44},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Adultery","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":45}]

I only need to fill the select option list with the crimeTypeDesc and crimeTypeId

**Error**
TypeError: crimeType.crimeTypeId is undefined

Comment: `JSON.stringify` **creates** JSON from an array or object. It returns a string. You certainly don't want to work on the string but directly on the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting JSON data back you don't want that `stringify` call. You should be able to replace your `success` method with something like this:

```
success:function(crimes){       
    var options = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < crimes.length; i++) {
        var crime = crimes[i];
        options += '<option value="' + crime.crimeTypeId + '">' + crime.crimeTypeDesc + '</option>';
    }
    $("select#offenceTypeId").html(options);
}
```

Comment: can you look at this issue i am facing please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746371/springmvc-custom-collection-editor-not-returning-data-to-jsp?noredirect=1#comment22402937_15746371

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to stringify the json object as that will flatten the object and you will no longer be able to use dot notation to access it's properties. Also, your other problem is the way you are trying to access these values. You say, crimeType.crimeTypeId[i] but you need to use crimeType[i].crimeTypeId as the index refers to which object within crimeType you are referring not which id within the crypeTypeIds you want (there is only one anyway) Here is a fiddle with the working script minus the ajax call. all you need to do is replace what you have in your success callback with what I have in the fiddle minus the json object. You can adjust it after that to your needs. I left a console log because I didn't have your html.

fiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/XJsH2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var crimeType = [{"crimeTypeDesc":"Incitement To Murder","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":39},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Sexual and Non Sexual Assults","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":40},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Pornography","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":41},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Censorship","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":42},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Statutory Rape","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":43},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Criminal Transmission Of HIV","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":44},{"crimeTypeDesc":"Adultery","crimeCatId":4,"crimeTypeId":45}];
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < crimeType.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + crimeType[i].crimeTypeId + '">' + crimeType[i].crimeTypeDesc + '</option>';
    }
    console.log(options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to stringify the data, because the function returns a JSON object.
jQuery has a for each funktion, which you can use to go through arrays.

```
success: function(data)
{
  var options = "";
  $.each(data, function(crime)
  {
    options += '<option value="' + crime.crimeTypeId + '">' + crime.crimeTypeDesc + '</option>';
  });
  $("select#offenceTypeId").html(options);
}
```