# SpringMVC Custom Collection Editor Not Returning Data To Jsp

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am binding a multi select list in spring the item does not get its data from the DAO the data is added from another select option list. The user clicks a button and the data is sent to the multi select option list using jquery.

When the form is posted databinding does not happen for the item since its a complex data type so i registered a CustomEditor and attached it to the @initbinder.

**EDITED**
I have updated the code the **CollectionEditor** is now returning a list of citizens back to the view however i am unable to get the data in the list to fill the select option. I am trying to add elements to the list however the jsp still selects remain null when return form the server.

Under is the code:

**CustomCollectionEditor**

```
@InitBinder("crime")    
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder victimbinder){
     victimbinder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "victims", new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class){
         protected Object convertElement(Object element){

             Citizens victims = new Citizens();

             String ssNumber = "";

             if (element instanceof String){
                ssNumber = (String) element;

             }                      

             logger.debug("element is ;" +element);

             try {

                int socialSecurityNumber = Integer.parseInt(ssNumber);
                victims = citizenManager.getCitizen(socialSecurityNumber);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {                     
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }

             return victims;        
         }

    });
```

**Jsp that is filled from DAO in controller**

This contains data filled form DAO class when the button is clicked it takes the data from the list on appends it to the other list under which is bind to the POJO

```
<label>Victims List</label><buttonid="addVictimBtn">/button>
<form:select path="" id="dbvictims" title="Victims Of Crime" class="victimLst">
<form:options items="${dbvictims.dbvictimList}" itemValue="socialSecurityNumber" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

**Jsp select item that is bind to POJO**

```
<label>Victims In Crime</label><button id="removeVictimBtn">-</button> 
<form:select path="victims" id="victims" title="Victims Of Crime"  multiple="multiple" class="victimLst">
<form:options items="${victimList}" itemValue="socialSecurityNumber" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select><form:errors path="victims" class="errors" />
```

Comment: I do not believe that select option labels are sent in an HTTP post, only the values.  I do not believe you can get said values directly.  You might be able to do something with a hidden field, however.

Comment: That is true so i will have to use the DAO class to select the names

Comment: @CodeChimp i have made an update i am now trying to render the list in the view

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If not, what does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: No errors and the html is blank no optoins in the list

Comment: I think i am doing something wrong with the list it seems empty

Comment: can anyone help with this issue

Comment: So, let me see if I can understand what is going on.  You have a Spring MVC controller in which you have an (at)InitBinder defined that creates an instance of CustomCollectionEditor.  This CustomCollectionEditor is used to populate the "victimList".  How is victimList getting set in your Model, though?

Comment: you have got the data in controller?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i am doing. I am thinking the return statement in the CustomCollectionEditor is suppose to return the data to the view

Comment: Yes the controller has data if you look at the logs i am actually receiving data from the post and then i am using a DAO to get the name of the victim

Comment: Can you also paste in the controller code?

Comment: @clav i updated and included controller code

Comment: It looks like you just want to send up an SSN and get a list of victims from the database for that SSN and then send that list back to the page as part of the model, is that correct? Which controller method are you calling to do this?

Comment: yes that is correct when the page first loads i use a get to fill al the list items form the database. Once the user enters data from the form and post the data i have a list item which is the multi list which gets its data from another list box filled from the database.

if there are any errors on the page i post the user back with the errors however because the multi list does not have a data source on the server side i have nothing send back to the list, this is where i saw i can register a custom collection editor where i can get the post values, create a list and send it back to theview

Comment: I am not calling a controller method to do this i am using the custom collection editor to return the list based on the posted values in the list

Comment: the multi list is populated using java script when the use select data from one list they click a button the items from that list(data source is database) is populated into the multi list.

Comment: for testing the validation i am using the crime_registration_save.htm url mapping i am ensuring the validation is working for all fields first before i actually save a record

Comment: the problem i am facing is when the user is send back form the controller with errors the multi list that was filled using java script is empty when it should have selected values i added

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Custom editors are used to bind posted data to a controller method parameter. So when data is posted, the custom binder will assemble the method parameter object before the controller method is called and that object gets passed to the controller method as a parameter. I would expect to see a controller method with a parameter that looks something like  `@RequestParam List<Citizen> victimList`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27429/discussion-between-dev-darin-and-clav)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution to this issue was very simple all of the work was already done in the **CustomCollectionEditor**. This is important when binding complex data types such as above. There may be other approaches to doing this however i find this to be a very clean and simple approach.

The return statement is very important since it binds to the item attribute of the element in the view. **CustomCollectionEditor** return a list of objects (*victims*) The use of the **DAO** gets the object from the database. This is important since the post only sends the select value not the label, hence we reconstruct the list and resend to the view.

The part of this that i omitted was passing the List Object from the controller back to the view.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="save.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handleSave(@Valid @ModelAttribute Crime crime, 
    BindingResult result,
    ModelMap m,
    Model model) throws Exception {


    if(result.hasErrors()){
           model.addAttribute("victimList",crime.getVictims());

    return new ModelAndView("*Your View*");
...............
```

Comment: Congratulations, finally you figure it out

Comment: You're welcome sir, I also recommend you to read the Spring web reference.